# Quit script after a certain condition is true

Tags: vimscript, vimscript-python

I have a script that checks for a certain condition (it checks if `pip` dependencies are installed). If they are installed and everything is ok, I want to import a bunch of python functions from my plugin so they are available to the user. However, if it's not available, I just want to print a message and skip the rest of the script.

Now, I was thinking of wrapping the whole operation in a function with abort like this:

```
function! checkPipDeps() abort
    ...
    if dependencyMissing
        throw "Your dependency is missing"
    endif

    ...
    python3 import dependency
endfunction

checkPipDeps()
```

but this does look clunky. I was wondering if there is a better solution where I can just return a dud value or something, that would allow me to skip the rest of the script but not mess up the initial loading process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:finish`:

```
if hasNoDependency()
    finish
endif

" all dependencies are met, good to go
" ...
```

I use it for minpac plugin manager (not only here of course):

```
if !exists('*minpac#init') | finish | endif

call minpac#init()
call minpac#add('k-takata/minpac', {'type': 'opt'})

"" My plugins
call minpac#add('git@github.com:habamax/vim-asciidoctor.git', {'rev': 'master'})
call minpac#add('git@github.com:habamax/vim-evalvim.git', {'rev': 'master'})
...
```